# How can I run python script when a google sheet get new value?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, airtable

I have a google sheet that 5 times a day append a new value to the sheet. I need to run a local python script everytime a value is included, how can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Are you familiar with the Google Sheet API yet?

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

That should get your started. As for automatizing running the script every time the sheet is overwritten, check the [metadata](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata) section to give you an idea of how to sync the data. Then, choose your favorite way to run your script periodically in the background of your system.